# float to bytearray, bytearray to float

Tags: python, arrays

```
import numpy as np 

Array = np.arange(0, 100.1, 0.1)
print(Array)

np.savetxt('1-100.txt', Array, fmt='%f') # 텍스트파일로 저장 

np.loadtxt('1-100.txt') 

array = np.loadtxt('1-100.txt') 
print(array)

data_array = []

for data in array:
  data_array.append(data)
  
import struct

byte_array = []
for data2 in data_array :
    byte_array.append(struct.pack('f',data2))
    
print(byte_array)
    
    

np.save('1-100npy',byte_array)

np.load('1-100npy.npy')

array2 = np.load('1-100npy.npy')

byte_array2 = []
for data3 in array2 :
    byte_array2.append(data3)




float_array = []
for data4 in byte_array2:
    float_array.append(struct.unpack('f',data4))



np.savetxt('1-100 2.txt',float_array, fmt = "%f'")
```

i wondering

```
float_array = []
for data4 in byte_array2:
    float_array.append(struct.unpack('f',data4))

error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes <- because of that
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

"np.save func" saves the value "b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'" as empty, literally.

Check "1-100npy.npy", you can see that.

To avoid the error, pass first item in byte_array2

```py
for data4 in byte_array2[1:]:
    float_array.append(struct.unpack('f',data4)[0])
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I have one more question

The value became a tuple.

i want array 
I hope it becomes an array(list)

Comment: I think getting first value of unpack func would be enough